# How to increment filed in mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
 const options = {
    $addToSet: { whoLikes: userId },
    $inc: { likesCount: 1 },
    new: true,
  };

collection.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: postId }, options)
```

What I want is increment **likesCount** only if **whoLikes** array length is get incremented.
Right now *likesCount* incrementing all the time doesn't matter how many objects inside *whoLikes* array.

I'm using mongoose, node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `findOneAndUpdate()` method
- Just check condition in your query part `whoLikes: { $ne: userId }` userId should not inside `whoLikes` array
- user `$push` instead of `$addToSet`
- other options should be in third parameter `new:true`

```
const options = {
    $push: { whoLikes: userId },
    $inc: { likesCount: 1 }
};

collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 
    _id: postId,
    whoLikes: { $ne: userId }
  }, 
  options,
  { new: true }
)
```

**Ex1:** Add UserID that is not present

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fU5gqUGTW_B)

**Ex2:** Add UserID that is already present

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RN6X4viYQtE)

Comment: The idea is update likes count only if whoLikes gets updated. whoLikes is a unique Set, it can be liked only once per user, thats why I use addToSet.

Comment: its not needed because we have added condition `whoLikes: { $ne: userId }` so it will not update second time if userId is already present. have you tested this query? i have added both the scenario in answer you can check.